# Prove that a given line doesn't pass through points with integer-coordinates

Tags: geometry

Let $A(5, 0)$ and $B(-2, 4)$ be two points. Prove that the line $AB$ doesn't pass through any point which has both coordinates integer values.

We have: $AB: 4x + 7y - 20 = 0$. This gives us:

$$x = \frac{20 - 7y}{4}$$
$$y = \frac{20 - 4x}{7}$$

I have no idea how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the full line or just the segment $AB$?

Comment: My mistake, it's just the segment.

Answer (score 2):

If $x,y$ are integers, then $4x + 7y - 20 = 0$ implies that $y$ is a multiple of $4$. However, there no multiples of $4$ strictly between $0$ and $4$, which are the $y$ coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Just check $y=1,2,3$, show that the corresponding $x$ values are not integers.